# Tap Recognizer of CustomCell on UITableViewCell can't be click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a nib as a custom cell on `UITableViewCellController`. There is a UIView with a recognizer on it. And, I added the nib inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but I can't click the UIView on the nib.

**CustomButton.swift** (I skipped the `tapRecognizer` as it's not important to show here):

```
class CustomButton: UIView {
    var tappable = false

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CustomButton.tapRecognizer))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }
}
```

**This is the code for the nib** :

```
@IBOutlet weak var customButton: CustomButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.customButton.tappable = true
}
```

The code from the **UITableViewCellController** :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // register nib
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil)
    self.tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customNib")
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customNib") as! CustomCell
    return cell
}
```

When I tried to debug the View Hierarchy, the whole page (including the Button (orange)) is covered by an UITableViewCellContentView.

[image]

Am I missing something on the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to  `userInteractionEnabled`.  enable userinteraction for view on that you wan to handle tap.

add something like

```
 self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Update :

Add your view (buttonview) on contentview of cell not direct on cell.

hope this will help :)

Comment: Thank you, but it's also doesn't work. I have added something like `tappable` on it to handle the interaction. When I tried to debug the view hierarchy, the button is covered by an UITableViewCellContentView.

Comment: It means I have to change my nib? I have to take the ButtonView out from the nib and should add it manually on the cell?

Comment: I don't think so. it should work. main concern is your button should on contentview not on cell. hierarchy should be cell-contentview-button

Answer (score 0):

First add a view in the nib of your cell and then add the button on that view. Directly adding button on the cell nib will make it hidden behind the content view.

Answer (score 0):

I should have create a nib using **TableViewCell** instead of **View**, and it's work. Thank you so much. :)